# TypeORM: how to call mutation from another mutation within the resolver

Tags: node.js, typeorm, typegraphql, node.js-typeorm

How do I call a mutation from another mutation within the same resolver in TypeORM if the function requires `context` as an argument?

Something like:

```
@Mutation()
async addNote(
    @Ctx() { req }: Context,
    @Arg('text', _type => string, { nullable: true }) text: string
  ) {
  // ...
  }

@Mutation()
async updateNote(
    @Ctx() { req }: Context,
    @Arg('text', _type => string, { nullable: true }) text: string
    @Arg('noteId', _type => Int, { nullable: true }) noteId: Int    
  ) {
  // ...
  if (noteDoesNotExist) {
    this.addNote(/* context? */, text) // <- here
  }
  // ...
}
```

Background: I'm trying to implement `upsert` (update mutation that creates element if it does not exist) but all the upsert implementations or the `.save()` methods I'm coming across seem to be mere workarounds full of trade-offs. The above seems to be the easiest I can do with my existing code while I find a cleaner solution.

Is it something I should not be doing at all?

Comment: Do not mix GraphQL (requests) with business/logic/data layer to increase maintainability and improve interoperability.
Your application should follow this flow: GraphQL (resolver) -> NoteService -> NoteRepository. Each of these is specialized in a single operation: GraphQL to handle the request -> Note service to handle your business logic (if not exists create) -> Note repository to handle your Database operations (create, read, update, delete, etc...). Therefore you can use multiple repository's functions inside your service.

Comment: I've made a project that uses this paradigm: [GraphQL resolver](https://github.com/GiovanniZotta/fog_cloud_project/blob/main/graphmarket/services/service-products/graphql/resolvers/ProductResolver.ts) -> [Product Service](https://github.com/GiovanniZotta/fog_cloud_project/blob/main/graphmarket/services/service-products/services/ProductService.ts) -> [Product Repository](https://github.com/GiovanniZotta/fog_cloud_project/blob/main/graphmarket/services/service-products/repositories/ProductRepository.ts)

Comment: Note that you can add functionalities (e.g logger, dependency injection) without directly touching the GraphQL resolver.

Comment: Thank you! That's very helpful, thanks for sharing =)

Comment: I've checked your project and we actually use a similar structure(minus repo). I'll rephrase my question:I have a database which stores entities `Users` and `MovieRatings`, and then I connect to a third party API which returns a third entity `Movies` (which I don't store) with all the movie info. The thing is one of my services is meant to get average MovieRatings for each rated movie in my DB and then use the returned movie ids to fetch  Movies (info), so I essentially need to access services of two different entities in the same function and I'm not too sure of how to structure (or do) that.

Comment: In the ```MovieRatingService``` you can **inject** another service (e.g ```MovieService``` that is a middleware between your app and the third party API). When a request must be served, you obtain the ratings, etc.. from you DB (via the injected repository/repositories) and make also a call to the ```MovieService``` (e.g ```await this.movieService.info(filmId)```) to obtain information about the film. Note that you can call the service(s)/repositories in parallel via [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Comment: That did it, thanks a lot mate =)